# Use-package doesn't find autoload

Tags: package, use-package, autoload

I expect the package to be `require`'d as soon as `mdi-insert` is called but I get:

> Error (use-package): spaceline :config: Symbol’s function definition is void: mdi-insert

`~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```el
(let ((default-directory (expand-file-name "lisp/" user-emacs-directory)))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))

(require 'package)
(setq-default
 load-prefer-newer t
 package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package t))
(setq-default
 use-package-always-defer t
 use-package-always-ensure t)

(use-package org
  :pin org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib)

(use-package spaceline
  :ensure nil
  :demand t
  :config
  (message (mdi-insert "star")))

(use-package mdi :ensure nil)
```

`~/.emacs.d/lisp/mdi/mdi.el`: https://github.com/angrybacon/mdi/blob/master/mdi.el#L1952-L1957

(`mdi` is a package I wrote myself and placed under `lisp/`)

Also, it works with `:demand t` in the declaration for `mdi`. But I would like to defer the package if possible.

Comment: You don't have anything there that would cause `mdi` to load. Try adding a `:commands mdi-insert` to the `use-package` form for `mdi`. (Also, as pointed out by @Basil: are you sure you called the function `mdi-insert`? It doesn't seem to appear in the linked `mdi.el`.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something, but the [linked `mdi.el`](https://github.com/angrybacon/mdi/blob/master/mdi.el) file does not define the function `mdi-insert`. Its main entry-point is the autoloaded function `mdi`.

Either way, if adding `:demand t` to the `mdi` `use-package` form results in the desired behaviour, this means that the definitions in `mdi.el` being used aren't being successfully autoloaded. Note that adding an autoload cookie (`;;;###autoload`) to an Elisp file does not automatically make it visible to Emacs. See the [Elisp Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) and [this post by lunaryorn](http://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/autoloads-in-emacs-lisp.html) for more information.

Some other observations:

- If you intend to byte-compile your `user-init-file`, especially in a `noninteractive` emacs, you may want to [`eval-and-compile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Compile.html) modifications to `load-path` (in your case, the call to `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path`).
- The `use-package` form for the `spaceline` package includes the `:demand t` clause. This means that the package will be required immediately, so everything in its `:config` clause should either be previously defined or autoloaded.
- Given my previous observation that `mdi.el` does not seem to define the function `mdi-insert`, I find it strange that adding `:demand t` to the `mdi` `use-package` form results in the desired behaviour. Again, I could be missing something, though.

Answer (score 0):

> (use-package mdi :ensure nil)

is mdi installed?

You might also have to add

> :after mdi

in use-package spaceline

Comment: If by installed you mean present under `lisp/mdi/` then yes. `:after` didn't help. But I doubt it needs it: for instance, `zenburn-with-color-variables` (macro from `zenburn.el`) is available in other `use-package` declarations I have (without needing `:after zenburn`).

Comment: Just to clarify, `mdi` is a package I wrote myself and placed in `lisp/`.

Comment: ah I see. I wonder if you need to add  `:load-path "lisp/"` like lunaryorn did in his use-package stanzas sometimes

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it.

Comment: Try adding `:load-path "lisp/mdi"`